# Как ускорить работу adb с эмулятором(Droid4X)?

Tags: android, эмулятор, adb

Когда работал с Bluestacks или с реальным устройством по USB, shell-команды выполнялись достаточно быстро, но когда перешел на Droid4X - команда input tap выполняется около 4-6 секунд, input text "123" - 1.5-2. Есть какие-либо способы ускорить выполнение команд?

P.S. В принципе, подойдут любые другие эмуляторы с близкой скоростью работы. Hyper-V у меня нет, поэтому эмулятор от VS не подходит, а Genymotion работает гораздо медленнее при тех же настройках.

Comment: я думаю, что проблема не в ADB, а в этом эмуляторе. Попробуйте другой эмулятор, например Genymotion

Comment: еще не плохой эмулятор у [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx). Работает без установки студии.

Comment: К сожалению, оба этих эмулятора не подходят для моих нужд.

Comment: Для каких нужд если не секрет?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему откатом с новой 0.9.0 версии Driod4X до 0.8.7. Теперь выполнение input tap происходит 300-500мс.